# Split files into a TFileStream

Tags: delphi

I'm doing two functions to join and divide files in a TFileStream, the code:

Join

```
procedure TFormHome.btnJoinClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  InStream, OutStream: TFileStream;
  OutFileName, InFileName1, InFileName2: string;
begin
  OutFileName := 'salida.out';
  InFileName1 := 'image.jpg';
  InFileName2 := 'test.exe';
  OutStream := TFileStream.Create(OutFileName, fmCreate);
  try
    InStream := TFileStream.Create(InFileName1, fmOpenRead);
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(InStream.Size));
    try
      OutStream.CopyFrom(InStream, InStream.Size);
    finally
      InStream.Free;
    end;
    InStream := TFileStream.Create(InFileName2, fmOpenRead);
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(InStream.Size));
    try
      OutStream.CopyFrom(InStream, InStream.Size);
    finally
      InStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    OutStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Divide

```
procedure TFormHome.btnUnJoinClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Source, Target: TStream;
  Buffer: array of Byte;
  i: Integer;
  SourceName, TargetNames: string;
  SizeTargets: Integer;
begin
  SourceName := 'salida.out';
  TargetNames := 'test.exe';
  SizeTargets := 2232832;
  Source := TFileStream.Create(SourceName, fmOpenRead);
  Target := TFileStream.Create(TargetNames, fmCreate);
  try
    SetLength(Buffer, SizeTargets);
    Source.ReadBuffer(Pointer(Buffer)^, Length(Buffer));
    Target.WriteBuffer(Buffer[0], Length(Buffer));
  finally
    Target.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that when I divide the files, files that are executable break and run when I want to show errors like:

```
  Windows can not find the file "route ..." Make sure the name is spelled correctly and try again
```

or

```
  The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running ... (and then talking about 32 or 64 bits)
```

Also check and the size of the executable in the second function is good.

The problem is that in the second code as a result have all the files are corrupted

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is that in the second code as a result have all the files are corrupted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are joining multiple input files together without indicating in the output where one file ends and the next begins. Your divide code has no idea which bytes belong to the JPG and which bytes belong to the EXE.

Case in point, the divide code you have shown is extracting the JPG bytes and saving them to an `.exe` file.  So of course that `.exe` file is not going to run correctly.

In order to extract the EXE, you have to extract/skip the JPG first, and that means you have to know how many bytes are in the JPG.  So you need to store the input file sizes in the joined output, not just their data, eg:

```
procedure TFormHome.btnJoinClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  OutStream: TFileStream;

  procedure AddFile(const FileName: sstring);
  var
    InStream: TStream;
    Size: Int64;
  begin
    InStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      Size := InStream.Size;
      OutStream.WriteBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
      OutStream.CopyFrom(InStream, Size);
    finally
      InStream.Free;
    end;
  end;

begin
  OutStream := TFileStream.Create('salida.out', fmCreate);
  try
    AddFile('image.jpg');
    AddFile('test.exe');
  finally
    OutStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormHome.btnUnJoinClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Source: TStream;

  procedure SkipFile;
  var
    Size: Int64;
  begin
    Source.ReadBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
    Source.Seek(Size, soCurrent);
  end;

  procedure ExtractFile(const FileName: string);
  var
    Target: TStream;
    Size: Int64;
  begin
    Source.ReadBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));

    Target := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
    try
      Target.CopyFrom(Source, Size);
    finally
      Target.Free;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Source := TFileStream.Create('salida.out', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    SkipFile;
    ExtractFile('test.exe');
  finally
    Source.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I would suggest that you consider storing the filenames as well:

```
procedure TFormHome.btnJoinClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  OutStream: TFileStream;

  procedure AddFile(const FileName: string);
  var
    InStream: TStream;
    Name: UTF8String;
    Len: Integer;
    FileSize, TotalSize: Int64;
  begin
    InStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      Name := UTF8String(ExtractFileName(FileName));
      Len := Length(Name);

      FileSize := InStream.Size;

      TotalSize := SizeOf(Len) + Len + SizeOf(FileSize) + FileSize;
      OutStream.WriteBuffer(TotalSize, SizeOf(TotalSize));

      OutStream.WriteBuffer(Len, SizeOf(Len));
      OutStream.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(Name)^, Len);
      OutStream.WriteBuffer(FileSize, SizeOf(FileSize));
      OutStream.CopyFrom(InStream, FileSize);
    finally
      InStream.Free;
    end;
  end;

begin
  OutStream := TFileStream.Create('salida.out', fmCreate);
  try
    AddFile('image.jpg');
    AddFile('test.exe');
  finally
    OutStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormHome.btnUnJoinClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Source: TStream;

  procedure SkipFile;
  var
    TotalSize: Int64;
  begin
    Source.ReadBuffer(TotalSize, SizeOf(TotalSize));
    Source.Seek(TotalSize, soCurrent);
  end;

  procedure ExtractFile;
  var
    Target: TStream;
    TotalSize, FileSize: Int64;
    Name: UTF8String;
    Len: Integer;
    Pos: Int64;
  begin
    Source.ReadBuffer(TotalSize, SizeOf(TotalSize));
    Pos := Source.Position;

    Source.ReadBuffer(Len, SizeOf(Len));
    SetLength(Name, Len);
    Source.ReadBuffer(PAnsiChar(Name)^, Len);

    Source.ReadBuffer(FileSize, SizeOf(FileSize));

    Target := TFileStream.Create(String(Name), fmCreate);
    try
      Target.CopyFrom(Source, FileSize);
    finally
      Target.Free;
    end;

    if (Source.Position - Pos) <> TotalSize then
      raise Exception.Create('Extract failed. Bad position');
  end;

begin
  Source := TFileStream.Create('salida.out', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    SkipFile;
    ExtractFile;
  finally
    Source.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy Lebeau.